# how to avoid or disable autoComplete in text input for Redux form?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-form

**i am using ReactJS and ReduxJS to construct my application .**

I created my form using Redux-Form and there are many text input and for one of them ,i am using **onkeyDown** event to increase and decrease number in my text

> so when i click up arrow or enter first digit the text is auto
>   completed with previous date entered(history) that disturb when i
>   click another up arrow

[Hint] I tried `AutoComplete=off`   and did not work

[image]

Comment: You dont. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just have the attribute cased incorrectly.  You *can* use the following 3 attributes on the input:

```
autoComplete="off"
autoCorrect="off"
spellCheck="off"
```

Notice that each are camel case.

Comment: It should be `autoComplete={false}
              autoCorrect={false}
              spellCheck={false}`. But still.. It's not working

Comment: @Darex1991 autocorrect values are off/on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocorrect.  I do this. and it does work.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it on React-native and redux it's showing me an error about propTypes- that property should be boolean.

Comment: React-native uses a completely different set of input elements.  This question was about the web.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like `autoComplete="off"` no longer works in Chrome. A workaround is to either set `autoComplete="new-password"` or a value not supported: `autoComplete="something-unsupported"`.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried all of the above example but this one is worked for me autoComplete="off"