# How to disable Chrome autocomplete in Redux-Form

Tags: reactjs

I am using a React redux-form input and this is my code:

```
return (
        <Field
          key={name}
          component={SurveyField}
          type="text"
          label={label}
          name={name}
          autocomplete="off"
        />
      );
```

I don't want chrome to autoComplete the form.
I have tried both but none working.

```
autocomplete="off"
autoComplete="off"
```

I suppose Chrome just ignores the autoComplete. I have seen the other StackOverflow questions but they are not helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid or disable autoComplete in text input for Redux form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056858/how-to-avoid-or-disable-autocomplete-in-text-input-for-redux-form)

Comment: (tl;dr: `autoComplete`, not `autocomplete`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable chrome auto complete feature in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347574/disable-chrome-auto-complete-feature-in-react-js)

Comment: You all give links with possible duplicates, but there are no working solutions with redux form

Answer (score 1):

I find that adding the autocomplete property to the `<input autoComplete="off"/>` tag defined in your component callback function rather than depending on the redux-form `<Field />` tag to pass this property to DOM will properly set this property in the html generated and `autocomplete="off"` will work as expected.